# Making .load return without the wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
.load('test.html #example')
```

How can I return `#example`'s contents without the `<div id="example">` wrapper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use jQuery's [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) instead of load.

Use it's callback function to manipulate the returned data:

```
$.get('test.html', function(data) {
  alert($(data).find('#example').html());
});
```

Comment: But how can I return the contents of that one element?

Comment: I hate using `.load` and I've only been using it for this one purpose. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

`.load()` should accept any selector that can be parsed with sizzle :

```
.load('test.html #example > *')
```

From the docs :

> If one or more space characters are included in the string, the
>   portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a
>   jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.

Comment: You'll loose any text children of #example